# Add "virtual" screen in my PC like a second screen connected

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, .desktop

I would like to know if there is any software that allows me to add a second "*virtual*" screen to my computer.

I would like to add this screen over my actual screen. Because a picture is worth a thousand words I added this picture:

[image]

I would like to add there a video, some folders, execute any software... The behaviour should be exactly like another screen, just over the original one.

I know about the "Allways on top" functionality, I would like to have this second virtual display configurable about the place and size. Maybe there is a way to customize the screen without virtualizing a new one.

- Does anyone knows any software to do this ?
- Is there any way to add virtual displays on any OS ?
- Is there any book/doc that I could read to learn about virtualizing hardware ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use VNC to connect to your PC with another session as mentioned in this link

[virtual-vnc-screen-workspace](https://superuser.com/questions/32455/virtual-vnc-screen-workspace)

Comment: Mmmm... Sounds interesting, I will try this. Thanks !!

Comment: your question was interesting for me too , and i will try it next week

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to get this behavior using the "Always On Top" option as you mentioned. Just start the new program, resize and move it to where you want it to be overplayed (top right in your example), and then right click on it's title bar and click:

- Always On Top
- Always on Visible Workspace

If this does not fulfill your requirements, and the problem is that you would like the behavior to be repeated for many programs, without you needing to do the above steps, you can try installing VirtualBox (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox) or VMWare. Then make an Ubuntu VM, and run programs in there. You would only need to perform the above actions once per session, but this solution has other limitations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I have said I'm aware about the **allways on top** functionality. And a Virtual Machine doesn't fit what I'm looking for. I want to virtualize the hardware in my PC, not a full virtual machine